# Reading line from a file adding additional line

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the contents of my file ITEM.dat is

DB1:TEST1:Y

DB2:TEST2:N

Code is

```
MYFILE='/tmp/ITEM.dat'
M_ITMES=['TEST1'] 
for ITEM in ITMES:
if ITEM in open(MYFILE):
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        ITEM_YN=(line.split(':'))[2]
        print(ITEM_YN)
```

The print command results in additional blank line after Y

```
Y
```

This does not occur when I use

```
ITEM_YN=(line.split(':'))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`line` includes the new line character as does the final item in `line.split(':')`. Since you likely want to use that item for other things, trim the newline before the split:

```
ITEM_YN = line.strip().split(':')[2]
```

Notice, I also got rid of those extra unneeded parens.